Extrude curve look wrong
I import world map.svg to my file. Then when I try to extrude it, it only extrude the line on the edge. I try convert to mesh, do it in edit mode, use geometry node and it still the same


I find out why it happen, It because of the material, the face still there but it is invisible.

The top and bottom aren't filled.
1)Select the curve
2)Go to 'Object Data Properties'
3)Select '2D'
4)Go to 'Geometry' and enter an extrude value greater than zero.
5)Under 2D>'fill mode'> specify 'both'
Using a curve shaped like a circle we will get a mesh that looks like a cylinder from these steps- should work with your country .svg as long as it is converted to a curve, and the shape is closed.

Another approach you asked about is Geometry Nodes.  In this case you can use the fill curve node, and use a duplicate and set position to get the missing surfaces.


I found out why it happened, it because of my material, I may have change some setting that cause this, I think I will close this

@Nguyễn Nhật Anh it is better to include your solution than close it- and if you found my answer useful to upvote it.  I have also added part of your question about geometry nodes.

Yes thiss answer is usefull, I am testing it. And I want to ask more:

I am import a world map SVG and want to make line between countries clear (it look like it merge when look from top), how can I highlight the outline ? with geometry node, or material shader
Another way I can think of is set different extrude value, can I do it with expression, or with geometry
I also want to use gradient texture so map look more impress, how can I do it ?


Please make that a separate question rather than adding it on the end of this one!

Sr, I will create another one
